# I cannot import the module "ns-ui-category/modal-view/basics/modal-view-page" in Nativescript

Tags: javascript, module, modal-dialog, nativescript

```
const modalViewModule = "ns-ui-category/modal-view/basics/modal-view-page";
//code in the middle
function openModal(args) {
    const mainView = args.object;
    const option = {
        context: { title: "...", description: "..." },
        closeCallback: (title, description) => {
            // Receive data from the modal view. e.g. username & password
            alert(`Title: ${title} : Description: ${description}`);
        },
        fullscreen: true
    };
    mainView.showModal(modalViewModule, option);

}
exports.openModal = openModal;
```

When I try to use this module, it says:
**Failed to load component from module**

Comment: There is no such namespace in `tns-core-modules` - it is probably copy/pasted from a sample demo where the path is leading to a folder that contains the modal page.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to check it. Thanks.